# Reflective diamond material

Tags: materials

I need help on how to make this kind of reflective diamond material in blender. Im doing visuals for an artist and i can’t find any good tutorials/posts on how to achieve this kind of effect.

[image]

Comment: do you want this material to work in eevee or cycles ??

Comment: Please read [ask], did you try researching the [various tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=eevee+diamond+material) available on the web.

Comment: I woud like this to work on cycles

Comment: do you have other pictures of the same object?